# React native: Change selected item color

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

My drawer navigation is a stack navigation, that mean I creat a custom drawer as a stack navigation like that:

```
class DrawerComponent extends React.Component {

  navigateToScreen = (route) => (
  () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
});


  render() {

    return (
          <ScrollView style={Styles.containerDrawer}>
            <View style={Styles.logoContainer}>
              <Image source={Images.logo}
                style={Styles.imageStyle}
                resizeMode={'contain'}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={Styles.blocksContainer}>
              <View style={Styles.firstBlock}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[Styles.buttonMenue, Styles.elevationButton, Styles.bgButton, Styles.centerContent]}
                  onPress= {this.navigateToScreen('Messages')}
                >
                  <IconMCI
                    name="message-text-outline" size={wp('10%')} color= '#000'
                    style={Styles.iconStyle}
                  />
                  <Text style={Styles.textButton}>الرسائل</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={[Styles.buttonMenue, Styles.elevationButton, Styles.bgButton, Styles.centerContent]}
                  onPress= {this.navigateToScreen('Home')}
                >
                  <IconSI
                    name="home" size={wp('10%')} color= '#000'
                    style={Styles.iconStyle}
                  />
                  <Text style={Styles.textButton}>الإستقبال</Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
```

My problem is that I can't change style of selected Item.

this is my drawer, it's look like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use states for handling click event for item and change class based on it, a sample example is provided below

```
    class DrawerComponent extends React.Component {

      state={
      clicked:true;
      }

      navigateToScreen = (route) => (
      () => {
        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: route
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    });


      render() {

        return (
             ...

                <View style={Styles.blocksContainer}>
                  <View style={Styles.firstBlock}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={!this.state.clicked?[Styles.buttonMenue, Styles.elevationButton, Styles.bgButton, Styles.centerContent]:['custom-style']}
                      onPress= {()=>{
    this.setState({clicked:true})
    this.navigateToScreen('Messages')
    }}
                    >
 ...
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.activeItemKey` inside your `render` method will give you the current item key like `Messages`, or `Home` in your case ... you could use to style the active item accordingly.

**Second**

If possible move your screens that your StackNavigator renders in the routeConfigs to your Drawer instead:

```
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Screen2: { screen: StackScreen2 },
  Screen3: { screen: StackScreen3 },
});
```

Comment: I think it works if I have Items in drawernavigation config 
but I have juve one stackNavigation

Comment: please share more about your navigation setup  (specially where and how you render your drawer) for the pic to be more clear...

Comment: But if do that I can't navigate from drawer to my screens because my items in costum drawer it's just touchableOpacity buttons

Comment: your `navigateToScreen` in your code did the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

this is more informations:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeStackNavigation from './HomeStackNavigation'
import Messages from '../Components/Messages/Messages';
import DrawerComponent from '../Components/Drawer/Drawer';
import {Platform, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
// import ScoreList from '../Components/ScoreList/ScoreList';

var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: { // entree (route name) : on peut la nommer comme on veut mais on prefere lui donner le meme nom que notre screen qu'on va afficher
      screen: HomeStackNavigation, // le screen qu'on va afficher IL DOIT ETRE UN STACK
    },
},
{
  drawerWidth: width*0.83,
  contentComponent: props =>
  {
    return(<DrawerComponent  {...props}/>)
  },
  drawerPosition: 'left',
},
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigation)
```

Comment: Great! .. the code in my answer will work perfectly ... since you're passing your `DrawerComponent` as the `contentComponent` ... try to console.log `this.props.activeItemKey` in your render method for testing

Comment: I have 'home' when I console.log it !! 
I think it's because of this : const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home:       screen: HomeStackNavigation,
    },
},